# What is the purpose of putting a value in carrots in assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm referring to '<' and '>'. I've seen it crop up before in x86 assembly, and I heard someone refer to putting values in carrots in MIPS assembly. So what do they do?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you saw it somewhere: include some example code. (First time I've heard angled brackets called "carrots". The person telling you this may have said 'carets' - which is, to me, actually this `^` symbol.)

Comment: Would depend on your assembler, but I can't think of any that does that. Disassemblers sometimes use it for additional information, such as symbol names.

Comment: Yep that makes way more sense. I was just extremely confused. I understand what they were trying to say now. Thank you!